# Chrome-Mobile PWA Fullscreen: App Area Exeeds HTML Height

Tags: android, html, css, progressive-web-apps, mobile-chrome

So, I got an Angular PWA, which is set to run in full screen.
But when I set the `"display": "fullscreen"` in the webmanifest, instead of `"display": "standalone"` I get an extra piece of scrollable content that is exactly the size of the now hidden android navigation bar.

[image: html is 664 pixel in height, but somehow I got a white bar at the bottom of the screen]

As you can see in the image, the bar i am talking about is not even part of the `html` tag, but is below it. I am not sure if I even could control it with CSS

This bar is below the footer, and is always the same color as the `<body>` background color.
It only appears in fullscreen mode of the installed PWA. In Standalone or Browser mode, it does not appear.
When I open the app, the footer is at the bottom of the screen and the bar is outside of the screen, but even on the page in the image - which is not scrollable due to the content amount - i somehow can scroll down to make this bar visible.

Changing the `<html>` or `<body>` height does not yield results.
How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Did you already solve this? I have the same problem.

Comment: No, still not solved. We just decided to use standalone mode for now

Comment: Did you find any work around for this yet?

Comment: If I had, I would've postet an answer

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem after updating chrome on android last week to 113.0.5672.77. My fullscreen web apps worked fine on older chrome versions, so I guess this is a bug and should be reported.

Comment: This should be added as a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you use ionic just overflow-y hidden and if you use height 100vh
use height 100dvh

Comment: I am not using ionic, and I am not even sure where to place the overflow-y, because the bar is not even a part of my application, according to the marked area in chrome dev tools. Anyway, using it in the `HTML` or `body` didnt do much

Answer (score 0):

It seems that adding `interactive-widget=resizes-content` to the viewport works well.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, interactive-widget=resizes-content">
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100svh;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).