# PWA fullscreen mode incorrect page height

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

PWA application in fullscreen mode defined in manifest has bigger page height than viewport size. It does not depend on the content of the page and persists even on a blank page.
This causes an extra overscroll to appear on the page and "position: fixed" elemets to move up and down with the scroll. Is there any way to fix it?

I also found exactly the same topics on stackoverflow, but there is still no solution:

- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76013413/chrome-mobile-pwa-fullscreen-app-area-exeeds-html-height](https://stackoverflow.com)
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76234229/fullscreen-home-screen-web-app-on-android-phone-has-48px-overflow-in-chrome-h?noredirect=1&lq=1](https://stackoverflow.com)

This behavior appeared recently and is reproduced with chrome version 114.0.5735.130, Android 9, Redmi 6A Build/PPR1.180610.011

Removing chrome updates in app settings fixes the problem, but the preinstalled Chrome version is 80.0 and it is too old.

Comment: Did you find any work around for this?

Comment: @DanKanze unfortunately not, the bug remains unresolved https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1457883

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me with several Android devices:

1. In the PWA manifest, replace `fullscreen` with `standalone`:

```json
display: "standalone"
```

2. In the Javascript code, call [requestFullscreen()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullscreen) on the root element:

```js
document.documentElement.requestFullscreen()
```

NB: The little drawback with that solution is that it requires a [recent user interaction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/User_activation#transient_activation) with the app.